# Looping over string representation of number in Julia unexpected behaviour

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm trying to understand why `int("0") > 0` evaluates to `false` while `all([int(i) > 0 for i in "0"])` evaluates to `true`. Interestingly, `[all(i != "0" for i in "0"]` also evaluates to `true`.

How can I get my list comprehension to evaluate correctly, that is, catch the "0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` is being called with different types, because iterating over a string is giving `Char` objects, not strings of length 1:

```
julia> typeof("0")
ASCIIString (constructor with 2 methods)

julia> [typeof(x) for x in "0"]
1-element Array{Type{Char},1}:
 Char
```

and when given a `Char`, Julia's `int` is more like Python's `ord`:

```
julia> int("0")
0

julia> int("0"[1])
48
```

which gives rise to what you see:

```
julia> [int(i) for i in "0"]
1-element Array{Int32,1}:
 48

julia> [int(i) > 0 for i in "0"]
1-element Array{Bool,1}:
 true

julia> all([int(i) > 0 for i in "0"])
true
```

There are lots of ways you could get this to behave as you expect, e.g. use `parseint` or simply convert back to a string:

```
julia> [parseint(i) for i in "0"]
1-element Array{Int32,1}:
 0

julia> [int(string(i)) for i in "0"]
1-element Array{Int32,1}:
 0
```